# Git Log Filter PowerShell output

Tags: git, powershell, azure-devops, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I managed to get a list of pre-commits and commits by using PowerShell script but noticed some unwanted lines on the result is there any way to filter only commit and Pre-commit-Verified from the list? user entered description data. I am new to PowerShell help is much appreciated

```
git log  -5 --no-merges master  | Select-String -Pattern "commit"
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

By default, [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string)'s `-Pattern` parameter accepts regexes ([regular expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)), which allow you to describe desired matches using sophisticated rules:

```
git log  -5 --no-merges master | 
  Select-String -Pattern '^commit |^\s+Precommit-'
```

- `^commit`  matches string `commit`, follwed by a space, at the start of a line (`^`)
- `|` is an alternation, meaning that the subexpression on either side is allowed to match.
- `^\s+Precommit-` matches string `Precommit-`, preceded by one or more (`+`) whitespace characters (`\s`) at the start of the line (`^`).

[This regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/Pf7jmX/1) not you to experiment with the regex interactively (the panel on the right side also contains an explanation).

Note: `Select-String`, like PowerShell in general, is case-*insensitive* by default. You can request case-*sensitive* matching with the `-CaseSensitive` switch.

Comment: I think OP's asking how to drop `commit` lines not immediately followed by a `Precommit-Validate` line, which this doesn't answer. Can `Select-String` work with arbitrary line gaggles like `sed` can?

Comment: @jthill, honestly, I'm not sure: if you look at what's highlighted in the image in the question, one way of reading that is that only that line should be omitted. Let's see what the OP says. `Select-String` doesn't directly support matching across multiple lines, except if you provide the whole file as a single, multi-line string as input. But there are definitely ways to make this work.

Comment: Ah. I see it now, I was supplying context from another question. If you've got a powershell answer for OP's previous question I'd be curious too.